# Почему возвращаеться только последний элемент?

Tags: php, json, foreach

Получаю список файлов. Хочу их возвратить в JSON , но только последний элемент возвращаеться.

```
<?
    $files = array_diff(scandir("plug/lol/"), ['.','..']);
    $array = [];
    $lole = [
    "count" => count($files)
    ];
    //echo json_encode($lole);
    foreach($files as $key=>$lol){
        $array = [
    "response" => [
    "count" => 16,
    "items" =>  [
    [
     "id"=>"$lol",
            "is_dir"=> "true"    
    ],
    ] ]];

    }
    print_r($array);
    ?>
```

Comment: Все верно, Вы же переменной **$array** в последней итерации цикла присваиваете значение

Comment: а как сделать чтобы вссе было нормально?

Comment: Попробуйте так: `array_push($array, [ тут ваш массив]);` - это сделать внутри цикла **foreach**

Answer (score 0):

А зачем этот код, если сount у вас в цикле присваивается при каждой итерации.

```
$lole = [
"count" => count($files)
];
```

В цикле сделайте присвоение следующим:

```
$array['response']['items'][] = [
    'id' => $lol,
    'is_dir' => true
];
```